# Jquery tab doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jquery and I'm trying to make a tab. 
I can't realize why this doesn't work

Here I have my HTML

```
<div class="tab-panels">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li rel="panel1"class="active">All</li>
        <li rel="panel2">Animals</li>
        <li rel="panel3">People</li>
        <li rel="panel4">Landscape</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel active">
        <img src="images/tab1.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/tab2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel">
        <img src="images/tab3.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/tab4.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="panel">
        <img src="images/tab5.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/tab6.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="panel4" class="panel">
        <img src="images/tab7.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/tab8.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('.tab-panels .tabs li').on('click', function({
        var $panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');
        $panel.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var panelToShow = $(this).attr('rel');

        $panel.find('.panel.active').show(300, showNextPanel);

            function showNextPanel(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');

            $('#'+panelToShow).slideDown(300, function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    }));
```

I made this code from a video that I watched, for this person the code worked perfectly, so I don't understand why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you include the jquery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax errors at `.on('click', function({` , close of `js` `});}));`

Try to call `.hide()` on `.panel` before displaying `.panel.active` ; substitute `.slideDown()` for `.show()`

```
$(function(){
    $(".tab-panels .tabs li").on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).siblings().add(".panel").removeClass("active");
        $(".panel").hide();
        $(this).addClass("active");

        var panelToShow = $(this).attr("rel");

        $("#" + panelToShow).addClass("active")
        .slideDown(300);
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nLu4Lpoy/

Comment: This worked to me, thank you for your answer. I tred to give you a point but I don't have enoght reputation

Answer (score 2):

Your forget to initialize it

try like this

```
$(function() {
    $( ".tab-panels" ).tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you misspelled the code(Assuming you have working css code for styling). See indicators shown below :

```
$(function () {
 $('.tab-panels .tabs li').on('click', function () { //<------ here
    var $panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');
    $panel.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var panelToShow = $(this).attr('rel');

    $panel.find('.panel.active').show(300, showNextPanel);

    function showNextPanel() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        $('#' + panelToShow).slideDown(300, function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    } //<------ here
  });
}); //<------ here(must close dom ready function)
```

Comment: I try this but like the first comment this add more photos when I press the diferents categories. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax errors in your jQuery, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.tab-panels .tabs li').on('click', function(e){

        var $panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');
        $panel.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var panelToShow = $(this).attr('rel');

        $panel.find('.panel.active').show(300, showNextPanel);

        function showNextPanel(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');

            $('#'+panelToShow).slideDown(300, function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        };
    });
 });
```

[Quick JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86fe4m18/3/)

Your first click function was not set up properly and the end wasn't closed right. You can usually solve something like this easier by keeping functions spaced out well, grouping your variables, etc..

Comment: Thanks, for your answer I try this but start to add more photos.